# Run throw array of associative array and find keys

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have two arrays that look like this:

(this one is ordered by *value_max*)

```
$max_values = [
    ["name" => "john", "id" => 5, "value_max" => 500], 
    ["name" => "john", "id" => 3, "value_max" => 200], 
    ...
];

$min_values = [
    ["name" => "john", "id" => 5, "value_min" => 100], 
    ["name" => "john", "id" => 3, "value_min" => 150], 
    ...
];
```

And I need to have a final array like this:

(This one stills need to be ordered by *value_max*, so I assume I could just overwrite the first array with the calculations done with the second)

```
$max_and_difference_values = [
    ["name" => "john", "id" => 5, "value_max" => 500, "difference_value" => 400],
    ["name" => "john", "id" => 3, "value_max" => 200, "difference_value" => 50 ], 
    ...
];
```

My question is pretty straight: What is the best/effective way to run through both first arrays and build the last one.  Assuming that the size of the arrays can be of around 150 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid looping through all arrays repeatedly, index one array by the field you want to merge on, i.e. the `'id'` key:

```
$second = array_combine(array_map(function ($i) { return $i['id']; }, $second_array), $second_array);
```

Then looping through the other and comparing the values is pretty easy:

```
$third = array();
foreach ($first_array as $i) {
    $third[] = $i + array('difference_value' => $i['value_max'] - $second[$i['id']]['value_min']);
}
```

If it's guaranteed that both arrays will have exactly matching keys, you don't even need the first step and just go by already existing keys.

Comment: If the second array will have more keys than the first one, but I just want to combine the ones of the first array, this would still work?

Comment: Yes it will. As long as the second array is a superset of the first.

Comment: This answer looks really clean. There is one thing I don't understand though. If the second is not a superset, what would happen?

Comment: Then at some point `$second[$i['id']]` will be invalid and you'll get errors. If this is a concern, you'll need to check if that index `isset` at all.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I keep getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' " in that first line of array_combine. I fail to see why is it complaining on that because it seems all the parentheses are closed.

Comment: It's because you're using a PHP Version < 5.3. replace `function($i){return $i['id'];}` By `create_function('$i','return $i[\'id\'];')`

Comment: @Hommer What version of PHP is this running on? I was assuming 5.4 due to your array syntax. Or is that fake array syntax?

Comment: deceze, I created the syntax myself. Sorry.

Comment: Then, yeah, use the `create_function` equivalent or do it with a simple loop. But really, you should update your PHP to at least 5.3 nowadays.

Comment: deceze, why are you doing a map with $second_array, and then combining to $second_array again? Shouldn't you combine to first_array? What I am trying to say is that, what matters the most is that at the very end, all the elements of the first array are at the last array. And imagine that in the first array there are elements that are not in the first array.

Comment: I'm *indexing* the array by the ids. So you can directly access an entry by its id, instead of having to loop through it.

Comment: deceze, I got it now. This is an awesome answer. I think I am getting some errors due the version of php when doing this...$i + ['difference_value' => $i['value_max']]. I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['" .

Comment: Yes, I'm using your array syntax. This works on PHP 5.4+, you'll have to use the regular array syntax on older versions.

Comment: deceze I fail to see how I would do this in the old syntax. Any resources I could check?

Comment: @Hommer Updated for 5.3 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This will sort your array. So you can sort the second array.

```
<?php
$min_values = array(
    array("name" => "john", "id" => 5, "value_min" => 100), 
    array("name" => "john", "id" => 3, "value_min" => 150), 

);



function aasort (&$array, $key) {
    $sorter=array();
    $ret=array();
    reset($array);
    foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
        $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
    }
    asort($sorter);
    foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
        $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
    }
    $array=$ret;
}

aasort($min_values,"id");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($min_values);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

And then you can use the logic what Alessandro Minoccheri mentioned.

```
$arr = array();
for ($i=0; $i<count($first_array);$i++){
$arr['name'] = $first_array[$i]['name'];
$arr['id'] = $first_array[$i]['id'];
$arr['value_max'] = $first_array[$i]['value_max'];
$arr['difference_value'] = $first_array[$i]['value_max']-$second[$i['id']]['value_max']    ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have not shared how the second array with the minimum values is ordered (in itself and relative to the maximum values array), I'd say, index the minimum values by the id entry and then do the calculation in a second iteration. It should be fast enough, 150 elements is just "nothing":

```
$max_values = [
    ["name" => "john", "id" => 5, "value_max" => 500],
    ["name" => "john", "id" => 3, "value_max" => 200],
];

$min_values = [
    ["name" => "john", "id" => 5, "value_min" => 100],
    ["name" => "john", "id" => 3, "value_min" => 150],
];

$min_values_by_id = [];
foreach($min_values as $min) {
    $min_values_by_id[$min['id']] = $min['value_min'];
}

$max_and_difference_values = $max_values;
foreach($max_and_difference_values as &$entry)
{
    $entry['difference_value'] = $entry['value_max'] - $min_values_by_id[$entry['id']];
}
unset($entry);

print_r($max_and_difference_values);
```

This is just a straight forward example, nothing fancy. [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wFBxc3)

Answer (score 0):

the following works for me. I'm not a PHP expert though, i.e. I'm not so familiar with cloning (note the empty clone array). Note that it only copies existing properties (if one array does contain a min_value and another does only contain a some other key)

In essence

```
function convertArr( $arr ) {

    // Easy referencing without having to search through the arrays more than once for a matching id
    $new_arr = array();

    foreach( $arr as $array ) {

        $new_arr[ $array['id'] ] = cloneArr( $array );
    }

    return $new_arr;
}

function merge( $arr1, $arr2 ) {

    $convertedArr1 = convertArr( $arr1 );
    $convertedArr2 = convertArr( $arr2 );

    $arr = array();

    // Based on the ordered array
    foreach( $convertedArr1 as $array ) {

        $id = $array['id'];
        $tempArr = array();

        foreach( $convertedArr1[ $id ] as $k => $v ) {

            $tempArr[ $k ] = $v;
        }

        foreach( $convertedArr2[ $id ] as $k => $v ) {

            $tempArr[ $k ] = $v;
        }

        array_push( $arr, $tempArr );
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

Full example:

```
<?php

    //$arr1 = [ ["name" => "john", "id" => 5, "value_max" => 500], ["name" => "john", "id" => 3, "value_max" => 200] ];
    //$arr2 = [ ["name" => "john", "id" => 5, "value_min" => 100], ["name" => "john", "id" => 3, "value_min" => 150] ];

    $arr1 = array(

        array( "name" => "john", "id" => 5, "value_max" => 500 ),
        array( "name" => "john", "id" => 3, "value_max" => 200 )

    );

    $arr2 = array(

        array( "name" => "john", "id" => 5, "value_min" => 100 ),
        array( "name" => "john", "id" => 3, "value_min" => 150 )
    );

    function neatPrint( $arr ) {

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r( $arr );
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    echo "<h2>Before</h2>";
    neatPrint( $arr1 );
    neatPrint( $arr2 );
    echo "<hr/>";

    function cloneArr( $old ) {

        // I dunno how to properly clone
        return $old;
    }

    function convertArr( $arr ) {

        // Easy referencing without having to search through the arrays more than once for a matching id
        $new_arr = array();

        foreach( $arr as $array ) {

            $new_arr[ $array['id'] ] = cloneArr( $array );
        }

        return $new_arr;
    }

    function merge( $arr1, $arr2 ) {

        $convertedArr1 = convertArr( $arr1 );
        $convertedArr2 = convertArr( $arr2 );

        $arr = array();

        // Based on the ordered array
        foreach( $convertedArr1 as $array ) {

            $id = $array['id'];
            $tempArr = array();

            neatPrint( $convertedArr1[ $id ] );
            neatPrint( $convertedArr2[ $id ] );

            foreach( $convertedArr1[ $id ] as $k => $v ) {

                $tempArr[ $k ] = $v;
            }

            foreach( $convertedArr2[ $id ] as $k => $v ) {

                $tempArr[ $k ] = $v;
            }

            array_push( $arr, $tempArr );
        }

        echo "<h2>Result</h2>";
        return $arr;
    }

    echo "<h2>Loopthrough</h2>";

    neatPrint( merge( $arr1, $arr2 ) );
?>
```

Let me know what you think :-)

Answer (score -1):

if the element are in order try this code:

```
$arr = array();
for ($i=0; $i<count($first_array);$i++){
   $arr['name'] = $first_array[$i]['name'];
   $arr['id'] = $first_array[$i]['id'];
   $arr['value_max'] = $first_array[$i]['value_max'];
   $arr['difference_value'] = $first_array[$i]['value_max']-$second[$i['id']]['value_max'] ;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the elements of the first array are in order, but the elements on the second are not...

Comment: You're just repeatedly overwriting the same fields in `$arr`...?! Also, why no `foreach`?

Comment: Using `count()` in a for is a bad practice. Performance issues. You should count BEFORE and store it into a variable.